# Free tools for translate Android String XML resources.?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-translate

I am looking for a free tools to translate Android String XML from Chinese to English.

Google has support a tool, but it doesn't free. I am just running a sample code, and want to translate for understand about UI follow.

Can you guys advise to me a tool?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Google Translate as free choice.
copy each string and paste it into Google Translate and get required results. goto `translate.google.com`